# SimpleCursorAdapter - фильтр для курсора

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Использую SimpleCursorAdapter для отображения данных из локальной БД в **ListView** с кастомной разметкой. Вот так я создаю адаптер

```
Cursor cursor = mSqLiteDatabase.query("products", new String[]
{DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_ID,
DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_NAME,
DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_COUNT,
DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_LIST,
DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_TYPE,
DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_COMPLETE},  
null, null,  null, null, null);

String[] from =
{DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_NAME,
DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_COUNT,
DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_TYPE,
DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_COMPLETE};
int[] to = {R.id.ColMemberID, R.id.ColName, R.id.count_tv, R.id.chb_products};

adapter = new InteractiveArrayAdapter(ListBuilder.this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);

lv_products.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Я создал экземпляр курсора, массив с именами столбцов в БД и с идентификаторами View-компонентов из кастомной разметки. Созданный адаптер я даю на сьедание списку.

А вот класс самого адаптера...

```
public class InteractiveArrayAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter
{
    private int layout;


    public InteractiveArrayAdapter(Context _context, int _layout, Cursor _cursor, String[] _from, int[] _to) {
        super(_context, _layout, _cursor, _from, _to);
        layout = _layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context _context, Cursor _cursor) {


        String prod_name = _cursor.getString(_cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_NAME));
        String prod_count = _cursor.getString(_cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_COUNT));
        String prod_type = _cursor.getString(_cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_TYPE));
        int prod_complete = _cursor.getInt(_cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_COMPLETE));

        TextView name_prod_tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ColMemberID);
        TextView count_prod_tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ColName);
        TextView type_prod_tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.count_tv);
        CheckBox chb = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.chb_products);
        chb.setFocusable(false);
        chb.setClickable(false);
        name_prod_tv.setText(prod_name);
        count_prod_tv.setText(prod_count);
        type_prod_tv.setText(prod_type);
        chb.setChecked(prod_complete==1);
        }




    @Override
    public View newView(Context _context, Cursor _cursor, ViewGroup _parent)
    {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)_context.getSystemService(_context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(layout, _parent, false);

        return view;
    }

}
```

Управляю чекбоксами по нажатию на весь айтем ListView, в слушателе получаю id данной записи и с её помощью делаю разные запросы к БД  (удаление, например). Как видно выше, чекбоксы я заблокировал, ибо вся работа уже настроена в слушателе ListView, поэтому просьба насчёт этого не критиковать, тут все работает.

**Проблема в другом**
Моя база данных может содержать в себе данные не из одной категории, поэтому просто отобразить подряд все данные из таблицы мне не надо. Нужно реализовать некий фильтр, который будет сравнивать число из одной, специально предназначенной колонке с другим числом, которое пришло через put/getExtra с предыдущей активности и добавлять айтем в список только в случае совпадения этих чисел. Иначе же - фильтр просто-напросто будет пропускать эту строчку и переходить к следующей.

**Что же у меня получилось?**
Я сделал, чтобы весь код в методе bindView() выполнялся только в том случае, если вот это условие верно

```
         (_cursor.getInt(_cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_LIST))==extra);
```

Переменная extra - то самое число с предыдущей активности.
Ну, вообщем, добавив структуру if в этот метод я надеялся на исправленный баг, но оказалось, что напрасно. Вместо тех айтемов, которых вообще не должно быть, (так как они не прошли проверку на extra) - стали стоять **пустые** айтемы. Все стало ясно. Я делаю проверку на extra и в случае валидности выполняется код для простой вставки данных из БД в TextView и CheckBox.

**А как же сделать, чтобы при этой проверке вообще айтемов не было? Может их высоту нулевой сделать? :DDD**
Хотя, и это тоже непонятно как осуществить))

**PRОFIT!**
В качестве второго аргумента в методе query я поменял null на условие list=extra, тем самым применив фильтр для курсора, который будет брать только те данные, у которых в колонке list число, равное переменой extra

**UPD**
Теперь другие грабли :) При скроллинге ListView чекбоксы, покинувшие экран, при возвращении назад, теряют изменения. Как можно это исправить?

Comment: А вопрос ваш состоит в том, что...???

Comment: @metalurgus, правил. все

Comment: Скорее всего вам нужно делать запрос курсора уже с нужным фильтром средствами БД и SQL, чтобы в курсоре уже были только нужные данные, а не пытаться потом из всей кучи что то отфильтровать с помощью кода. Именно так работают с БД, составляют точные запросы, что именно надо получить в итоговой таблице, а не выбирают всю базу и потом из нее что то кодом отсеивают. Эти пять `null` в конце метода `query()` на самом деле мощный инструмент по фильтрации и сортировки БД прямо в запросе, но вы их не используете

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно получать `Cursor` с уже готовыми и отфильтрованными значениями средствами самой БД SQLite и языка SQL, а не выбирать всю таблицу и потом кодом пытаться что то отфильтровывать, тем более прямо в адаптере - это абсолютно не правильное решение. Адаптер должен только отобразить предоставленные ему данные , а не обрабатывать их.

SQL очень мощный язык и позволяет сделать ЛЮБУЮ выборку из БД только с нужными данными в итоговой возвращаемой таблице (в возвращаемом курсоре). То есть вам нужно с помощью SQL-запроса к БД получить итоговый курсор уже только с нужными значениями и потом уже его передать в адаптер, который просто преобразует эти значения в `View` для айтемов.

Именно так работают с БД - такие запросы во много раз быстрее, чем потом кодом фильтровать курсор и вообще это правильный подход.