# SimpleCursorAdapter + ListView: Чекбоксы теряются при скроллинге

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

Чекбоксы при уходе за экран, теряют свои положения при возвращении. Вот тут - [SimpleCursorAdapter - фильтр для курсора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/521142/simplecursoradapter-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d1%80-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0/521175?noredirect=1#comment642201_521175)
есть весь код (мой вопрос). Как реализовать метод для сохранения булевых значений? Неужели вместо курсора в адаптер мне нужно отправлять массив булевых значений? А как взятие данных через курсор в методе bindView()? Ведь курсор я уберу, а он нужен.

**Mетод для получения данных с БД**

```
private void getProductList()
{
    String filter = "list=" + intValue;
    final Cursor cursor = mSqLiteDatabase.query("products", new String[] {DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_ID,
        DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_NAME, DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_COUNT, DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_LIST, DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_TYPE, DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_COMPLETE}, 
        null, null,  null, null, null) ;  
    final Cursor cursorc = mSqLiteDatabase.query("products", new String[] {DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_ID,
                                                    DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_NAME, DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_COUNT, DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_LIST, DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_TYPE, DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_COMPLETE}, 
                                                filter, null,  null, null, null) ;
    final ArrayList<String> arrTblNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        while ( !cursor.isAfterLast() ) {
            if(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("list"))==intValue)
            {
            arrTblNames.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
            }
            cursor.moveToNext();
            }

        String[] from = {DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_NAME, DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_COUNT, DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_TYPE, DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_COMPLETE};
        int[] to = {R.id.ColMemberID, R.id.ColName, R.id.count_tv, R.id.chb_products};
        adapter = new InteractiveArrayAdapter(ListBuilder.this,
        R.layout.row,
        cursorc,
        from,
        to
        );
        //lv_products.setAdapter(adapter);

    }



    if(!arrTblNames.isEmpty()){
        empty_bd_layout.setAlpha(0);
        lv_products.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    else{
empty_bd_layout.setAlpha(255);
}
}
```

**И сам адаптер**

```
public class InteractiveArrayAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter
{
    private int layout;
    private boolean checked[];
    public InteractiveArrayAdapter(Context _context, int _layout, Cursor _cursor, String[] _from, int[] _to) {
        super(_context, _layout, _cursor, _from, _to);
        layout = _layout;
        int counts = _cursor.getCount();
        checked = new boolean[counts];

                for (int i = 0; i < counts; i++){

                    int checkMarker = _cursor.getInt(_cursor.getColumnIndex("complete"));
                    checked[i] = checkMarker == 1;
            }


    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context _context, Cursor _cursor) {




        String prod_name = _cursor.getString(_cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_NAME));
        String prod_count = _cursor.getString(_cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_COUNT));
        String prod_type = _cursor.getString(_cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_TYPE));
    //  int prod_complete = _cursor.getInt(_cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_COMPLETE));
        TextView name_prod_tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ColMemberID);
        TextView count_prod_tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ColName);
        TextView type_prod_tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.count_tv);
        CheckBox chb = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.chb_products);

        chb.setFocusable(false);

        chb.setClickable(false);

        name_prod_tv.setText(prod_name);

        count_prod_tv.setText(prod_count);

        type_prod_tv.setText(prod_type);

        chb.setChecked(checked[_cursor.getPosition()]);

        }
    @Override
    public View newView(Context _context, Cursor _cursor, ViewGroup _parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)_context.getSystemService(_context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(layout, _parent, false);
        return view;
    }
    public void setChecked(int position){
        // инвертируем значение при обработке клика этим методом
        checked[position]=!checked[position];
    }
}
```

**LogCat**
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-09 07:18:29.529 1468 1468 E     AndroidRuntime                               Process: ru.diskrim.listbuy, PID: 1468
05-09 07:18:29.529 1468 1468 E     AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.diskrim.listbuy/ru.diskrim.listbuy.ListBuilder}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 4
05-09 07:18:29.529 1468 1468 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
05-09 07:18:29.529 1468 1468 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
05-09 07:18:29.529 1468 1468 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
05-09 07:18:29.529 1468 1468 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
05-09 07:18:29.529 1468 1468 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-09 07:18:29.529 1468 1468 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-09 07:18:29.529 1468 1468 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
05-09 07:18:29.529 1468 1468 E     AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-09 07:18:29.529 1468 1468 E     AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-09 07:18:29.529 1468 1468 E     AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
05-09 07:18:29.529 1468 1468 E     AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
05-09 07:18:29.529 1468 1468 E     AndroidRuntime                               at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:117)
05-09 07:18:29.529 1468 1468 E     AndroidRuntime                               Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 4
05-09 07:18:29.529 1468 1468 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
05-09 07:18:29.529 1468 1468 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
05-09 07:18:29.529 1468 1468 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:68)
05-09 07:18:29.529 1468 1468 E     AndroidRuntime                               at ru.diskrim.listbuy.ListBuilder$InteractiveArrayAdapter.(ListBuilder.java:245)
05-09 07:18:29.529 1468 1468 E     AndroidRuntime                               at ru.diskrim.listbuy.ListBuilder.getProductList(ListBuilder.java:209)
05-09 07:18:29.529 1468 1468 E     AndroidRuntime                               at ru.diskrim.listbuy.ListBuilder.onCreate(ListBuilder.java:184)
05-09 07:18:29.529 1468 1468 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6033)
05-09 07:18:29.529 1468 1468 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
05-09 07:18:29.529 1468 1468 E     AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
05-09 07:18:29.529 1468 1468 E     AndroidRuntime                               ... 11 more

Comment: рекомендую все же изучить параметры метода `query()`/ Запрос должен выглядеть примерно так: `final Cursor cursorc = mSqLiteDatabase.query("products", new String[] {DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_ID, DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_NAME, DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_COUNT, DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_LIST, DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_TYPE, DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_COMPLETE}, 
                                                "list = ?", new String[] {""+ intValue],  null, null, null) ;`

Comment: @pavlofff, а как же строчка boolean[] checked?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решение мало чем отличается от [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/507146/177345), с той разницей, что вам нужно обрабатывать клики из активити, а не слушателем в адаптере.

Поскольку мы не можем изменять значения в курсоре, а только читать их оттуда, для запоминания текущего состояния чекбоксов требуется создать локальное хранилище.

В адаптер вам нужно передавать данные, которые должны быть отображены в виджете, в вашем случае это курсор с выборкой из БД. Вспомогательный массив булевых значений никуда передавать не нужно, он создается внутри адаптера.

Примерная реализация может выглядеть так:

```
private void getProductList()
{

    // Если требуется только имя, следует и запрашивать из БД только 
    //колонку с именем, а не все в кучу
    // Если требуется только записи с каким то условием, то их и надо запрашивать,
    // а не все в подряд, а потом выбирать нужные каким то циклом
    // так же эти данные включены и в курсор для адаптера и нет нужды 
    // получать то же самое дважды
    // final Cursor cursor = mSqLiteDatabase.query("products", new String[] {DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_ID, DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_NAME,"list = ?", new String[] {""+ intValue}, null, null, null) ;

    //то же самое, только нужные в адаптере колонки
    final Cursor cursorc = mSqLiteDatabase.query("products", new String[] {DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_ID,DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_NAME, DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_COUNT, DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_TYPE, DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_COMPLETE}, "list = ?", new String[] {""+ intValue}, null, null, null);

    final ArrayList<String> arrTblNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    // копирование данных из курсора в массив сильно упрощается,
    // так как у нас только нужные данные

    while ( cursorc.moveToNext() ) {
           arrTblNames.add(cursorc.getString(cursorc.getColumnIndex("name")));
           }

        String[] from = {DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_NAME, DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_COUNT, DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_TYPE, DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_COMPLETE};
        int[] to = {R.id.ColMemberID, R.id.ColName, R.id.count_tv, R.id.chb_products};
        adapter = new InteractiveArrayAdapter(ListBuilder.this,
        R.layout.row,
        cursorc,
        from,
        to
        );
        //lv_products.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    // у виджетов есть свойство Visiblity, которое управляет видимостью на
    // экране, зачем тут использовать прозрачность ?
    // я бы поменял всю логику вообще, исходя из условия ниже, 
    // зачем получаnь и формировать данные, если они могут не понадобится

    if(!arrTblNames.isEmpty()){
        empty_bd_layout.setAlpha(0);
        lv_products.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    else{
         empty_bd_layout.setAlpha(255);
    }
}
```

**адаптер:**

```
public class InteractiveArrayAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter
{
    private int layout;
    private boolean checked[];


    public InteractiveArrayAdapter(Context _context, int _layout, Cursor _cursor, String[] _from, int[] _to) {
        super(_context, _layout, _cursor, _from, _to);
        layout = _layout;
        // инициализируем вспомогательный массив начальными отметками чекбоксов из курсора

        checked = new boolean[_cursor.getCount()];
        int i = 0;
        while ( _cursor.moveToNext() ) {
           int checkMarker = _cursor.getInt(_cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_COMPLETE));
          checked[i] = (checkMarker == 1) ? true: false;
          i = i + 1;
        }

    // нужно вернуть указатель курсора в первоначальное положение
    // перед первой записью, для корректной работы адаптера
      _cursor.moveToPosition(-1); 
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context _context, Cursor _cursor) {


        String prod_name = _cursor.getString(_cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_NAME));
        String prod_count = _cursor.getString(_cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_COUNT));
        String prod_type = _cursor.getString(_cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_TYPE));

        // эта строка здесь теперь по видимому не нужна, поскольку значения отметок
        // из курсора мы уже извлекли
        //int prod_complete = _cursor.getInt(_cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_COMPLETE));

        TextView name_prod_tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ColMemberID);
        TextView count_prod_tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ColName);
        TextView type_prod_tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.count_tv);
        CheckBox chb = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.chb_products);
        chb.setFocusable(false);
        chb.setClickable(false);
        name_prod_tv.setText(prod_name);
        count_prod_tv.setText(prod_count);
        type_prod_tv.setText(prod_type);

        // устанавливаем чекбоксы по вспомогательному массиву, а не по курсору
        // получаем текущую позицию курсора (и соответственно адаптера) через его метод
        chb.setChecked(checked[_cursor.getPosition()]);
        }




    @Override
    public View newView(Context _context, Cursor _cursor, ViewGroup _parent)
    {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)_context.getSystemService(_context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(layout, _parent, false);

        return view;
    }

    // метод для фиксации изменений отметок чекбоксов из активити
    public void setChecked(int position){

        // инвертируем значение при обработке клика этим методом
        checked[position] = !checked[position];
    }

}
```

запись изменений в БД по отметкам чекбоксов у вас, насколько я помню, осуществляется при обработке клика в слушателе списка, поэтому в адаптер это действие не включено, но оно должно обязательно присутствовать, иначе при выходе из списка отметки будут утеряны.

Comment: теперь я средне все понял) вот только ошибка. в LogCat-E android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 2... ругается на строчку        int checkMarker = _cursor.getInt(_cursor.getColumnIndex("complete")); P.S когда вместо жёсткого названия столбца стояла ссылка на переменную из класса враппера, выдавало ту же ошибку

Comment: оно говорит, что выход из диапазона. Метод `getColumnIndex()` возвращает -1, а для массивов возможны индексы начиная с нуля. Сама причина в том, что в курсоре не существует колонки, к которой вы обращаетесь, в этом случае возвращается -1, а не номер колонки. Скорее всего неправильно написано имя колонки в запросе.

Comment: нет, имя колонки в запросе указано верно

Comment: и тем не менее, метод `getColumnIndex()` не может найти колонку с указанным именем. если имя написано верно, включая заглавные буквы, возможные пробелы в начале\конце или прочие путаницы с символами, то в полученном курсоре совсем нет этой колонки, смотрите запрос, который вы отправляете для получения курсора.

Comment: Попробуйте поставить просто номер этой колонки (отсчет начинается с нуля). Например, если данная колонка **четвертая** в таблице, то : `int checkMarker = _cursor.getInt(3);` Однако, само то, что размер курсора в стектрейсе указан в три колонки ( with a size of 2 - колонки 0,1,2) наводит на мысль об отсутствии нужной вам в полученном курсоре, смотрите свой запрос и включение этой колонки в выборку.

Comment: куда смотреть? на курсор? на метод query()? там у меня в statement стоит list=extra. То есть я беру только те колонки, в которых list равен динамичному числу.

Comment: убрал statement в курсоре, теперь ошибка index 10 requested with of size 10 но и сканирует он выходит всю таблицу. даже если я сейчас это сделаю, фильтр пропадет

Comment: Да, смотрите метод `query()` и пожалуйста, разберитесь, как составлять запросы в БД и как правильно организовать структуру БД, чтобы получать из нее требуемые данные. Я представления не имею, как и по каким принципам вы формируете курсор, но позаботьтесь о том, чтобы он включал все требуемые адаптеру колонки.

Comment: блин, в гугле не могли позаботиться о нормальном создании адаптера.. ладно, добавил код в вопрос. весь.

Comment: после бессонной ночи я окончательно сдаюсь :( Все правильно, массив инициализирую, заполняю его сам переменными true или false. Вывожу в логи - отлично. Только пытаюсь заполнить его курсором через цикл for - ошибка (index -1, size = кол-во отфильтрованных данных), а если адаптера передавать курсор без фильтра, то в ошибке index равен size. Голова болит. Уже по всякому пробовал

Comment: @СергейГрушин вы запрос `query()` поменяли, на тот который в комментарии к вопросу тоже?

Comment: конечно. там ещё вы квадратную скобку вместо фигурной закрыли)

Comment: дело в курсоре, да?

Comment: @СергейГрушин я немного исправил о иоткоментировал, попробуйте

Comment: Я понял, в чем тут дело и это я виноват, каюсь. Указатель курсора, полученный адаптером, стоит до первого элемента, а в циле не двигается  и отсюда проблемы, ведь в конструкторе адаптер не управляет указателем курсора.  Меня в свое время очень достала вся эта "оснастка" работающая с SQLite своей заморочностью и теперь я использую ORM. Исправил немного, в уме довольно сложно все предусмотреть, надеюсь причину и способ решения вы поймете и доработаете, в случае ошибок. Так же возможно надо вернуть указатель курсора перед передачей в адаптер, так как мы его двигали, но я не уверен.

Comment: преогромное человеческое спасибо! Все работает :)) Насчёт прозрачности - у меня есть панель одна, которая... А.. Я не знаю как объяснить - но все работает, я не трогаю)