# Скрытие элементов item в ListView по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: android, listview

Есть кастомный ListView в котором в каждом item несколько элементов.
При нажатии на кнопку в item я хочу скрыть текст в этом-же item.

в OnClickListener я пробую:

```
TextView ORANGE = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewUP);
         ORANGE.setVisibility(GONE);
```

Но TextView скрывается только в первом элементе.

Как по мне, то нужно сделать так:

```
TextView ORANGE = (TextView) (*тут указать позицию*).findViewById(R.id.TextViewUP);
         ORANGE.setVisibility(GONE);
```

Но не знаю как. Поделитесь, пожалуйста, опытом (и знаниями).

Код:

```
public class BoxAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context ctx;
    LayoutInflater lInflater;
    ArrayList<TaskIteamDeskribe> objects;


    BoxAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<TaskIteamDeskribe> tasks) {
        ctx = context;
        objects = tasks;
        lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return objects.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return objects.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int id) {
        return id;
    }


  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
               view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.taskiteam, parent, false);
            }
        TaskIteamDeskribe p = getTask(position);

        ivImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
        ivImg.setOnClickListener(Pausbtn);
    return view;
  }

    View.OnClickListener Pausbtn = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

     ImageView ivImg = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
               ivImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
               ivImg.setOnClickListener(Gobtn);

     TextView ORANGE = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewUP);
              ORANGE.setVisibility(GONE);
      }
    };
```

Comment: вам нужно делать это в методе `getView()` адаптера. Повешать там слушатель на текст и устанавливать ему видимость. Затем запоминать значение в отдельное хранилище с размером равным количеству позиций в списке, чтобы при прокрутке видимость.невидимость не терялась. Смотрите [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/521317/177345), в вашем случае вмеcто состояния чекбоксов будет видимость и адаптер видимо не на основе CursorAdapter, но принцип, думаю ясен. Вообще нужно больше кода, если вам нужна более полезная помощь.

Comment: А нельзя как-то сообщить ID или ПОЗИЦИЮ элемента, чтобы убирать его сразу из OnClick? Ведь поменять изображение кнопки можно, почему текст убрать нельзя?

Comment: Позиция элемента передается в метод getView(), конечно вы можете в onClick() скрывать элемент или я не понял о чем вы вообще, кому сообщить позицию и где onClick()